# Kotlin execute optional action

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a model with an optional higher-order function *(() -> Unit)?*

When I want to call that function, I'm wondering, how can I call it even been an optional.

I know this works

```
model.action?.invoke()
```

There is something similar to Swift?, where I could do:

```
model.action?()
```

I know, I can do too:

```
model.action?.let { action() }
```

Maybe this last one is the "better" way to go.
Do you know some "better" way?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the standard library function [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) as follows:

```
val actionResult = model.action?.let { it() }
```

Note that the receiver of `let` (`model.action`) is exposed as `it` inside the lamda.

Alternatively, and preferably IMO, invoke the function like this:

```
model.action?.invoke()
```

Answer (score 6):

It's a matter of one's personal preference, but I'd stay with the first variant, i.e.

```
model.action?.invoke()
```

Simply because it's just the [safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) of [invoke operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke) and it does not have the burden of adding higher-level function (i.e. `let`) into the expression.

Btw, in some cases if you write something like `model.action?.let { it() }` in Idea (at least it works for Android Studio which is based on Idea), you'll get a warning saying that `let` is useless here and you can safely replace it with the plain safe call.

Comment: Thanks @aga, yes, i like more that one, for me it's cleaner than the .let

Comment: I don’t really like the `invoke()`, but it’s an equally valid alternative

Answer (score 0):

If the function returns `unit`, I’d use `also`, not `let`. The former is a side-effecting construct, the latter for returning a value.